# Oracle SQL query Logic - Group by based on Date Difference

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by

Can someone help with ideas implementing the requirement described below :

[image]

Table above (in screenshot) maintains the job history of scheduled processes.

My requirement is to have a target table maintaining cumulative history as per below screenshot.

[image]

Refer below for source/target table structure and source sample records sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE "XHQ"."SHIFT_LOG" ("SEQUENCE_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
"JOB_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
"START_TS" DATE, 
"END_TS" DATE, 
"MINIMUM_VALUE" FLOAT(126), 
"MAXIMUM_VALUE" FLOAT(126), 
"AVERAGE_VALUE" FLOAT(126), 
"USERID" NVARCHAR2(80) );

Insert into XHQ.SHIFT_LOG (SEQUENCE_ID,JOB_ID,START_TS,END_TS,MINIMUM_VALUE,MAXIMUM_VALUE,AVERAGE_VALUE,USERID) values (10908,12000,to_date('01-MAY-15','DD-MON-RR'),null,null,null,null,'admin');
Insert into XHQ.SHIFT_LOG (SEQUENCE_ID,JOB_ID,START_TS,END_TS,MINIMUM_VALUE,MAXIMUM_VALUE,AVERAGE_VALUE,USERID) values (10825,12000,to_date('29-APR-15','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('01-MAY-15','DD-MON-RR'),null,null,null,'admin');
Insert into XHQ.SHIFT_LOG (SEQUENCE_ID,JOB_ID,START_TS,END_TS,MINIMUM_VALUE,MAXIMUM_VALUE,AVERAGE_VALUE,USERID) values (10800,12000,to_date('29-APR-15','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('29-APR-15','DD-MON-RR'),5,10,7.5,'admin');
Insert into XHQ.SHIFT_LOG (SEQUENCE_ID,JOB_ID,START_TS,END_TS,MINIMUM_VALUE,MAXIMUM_VALUE,AVERAGE_VALUE,USERID) values (10725,10500,to_date('28-APR-15','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('29-APR-15','DD-MON-RR'),4,8,6,'admin');
Insert into XHQ.SHIFT_LOG (SEQUENCE_ID,JOB_ID,START_TS,END_TS,MINIMUM_VALUE,MAXIMUM_VALUE,AVERAGE_VALUE,USERID) values (10625,10500,to_date('27-APR-15','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('27-APR-15','DD-MON-RR'),6,6,6,'admin');
Insert into XHQ.SHIFT_LOG (SEQUENCE_ID,JOB_ID,START_TS,END_TS,MINIMUM_VALUE,MAXIMUM_VALUE,AVERAGE_VALUE,USERID) values (10620,10500,to_date('23-APR-15','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('27-APR-15','DD-MON-RR'),null,null,null,'admin');
Insert into XHQ.SHIFT_LOG (SEQUENCE_ID,JOB_ID,START_TS,END_TS,MINIMUM_VALUE,MAXIMUM_VALUE,AVERAGE_VALUE,USERID) values (10525,10500,to_date('22-APR-15','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('23-APR-15','DD-MON-RR'),null,null,null,'admin');
Insert into XHQ.SHIFT_LOG (SEQUENCE_ID,JOB_ID,START_TS,END_TS,MINIMUM_VALUE,MAXIMUM_VALUE,AVERAGE_VALUE,USERID) values (10510,10500,to_date('18-APR-15','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('20-APR-15','DD-MON-RR'),8,16,8,'admin');
```

Let me give an overview of the requirement.

Consider JobID = 10500

- As per sequenceid:10510, It has started at 18-apr and ran till 20-apr. Once its completed successfully it gets min, max, avg value corresponding to it as summary.
- However if we consider sequence id: 10525, it started by 22-apr and ran till 23-apr. However due to some network outage it stopped in middle for few minutes and started again. Because of it it has min, max, avg value as NULL since the job is incomplete. Again it had another network issue on 27th apr so it was stopped and resumed again. Finally on 27th apr (sequence id: 10625) it got completed succesfully and min, max, avg value was assigned to it.

[image]

In this case record entries belonging to sequence id's 10625, 10620 and 10525  needs to be considered as single group and start_ts from sequence id 10525 needs to get assigned to sequenceid 10625 as below

[image]

One exception to above case is, if end_ts is null (sequence id : 10908) (it denotes currently active job).

[image]

Here grouping should be with sequence id: 10825 and output should be like as below screenshot.

[image]

Let me know if you require any clarifications.

Thanks in advance for your time and valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT sequence_id, job_id, new_start_ts as start_ts, end_ts,
       minimum_value, maximum_value, average_value, userid
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           min( start_ts ) over ( partition by job_id, new_seq_id ) As new_start_ts
    FROM (
          SELECT t.* ,
                 first_value( case when minimum_value is not null then sequence_id end IGNORE NULLS )
                 over (partition by job_id order by sequence_id rows between current row and unbounded following ) as new_seq_id
          FROM SHIFT_LOG t
    ) t
)
WHERE minimum_value IS NOT NULL 
  OR new_seq_id IS NULL AND end_ts IS NULL
ORDER BY sequence_id desc;
```

Comment: Could you please tell the order of execution of logical operators in where, is it like 1) `(minimum_value IS NOT NULL 
  OR new_seq_id IS NULL) AND end_ts IS NULL`  or is it like 2)`minimum_value IS NOT NULL 
  OR (new_seq_id IS NULL AND end_ts IS NULL)` . I mean which is evaluated first.

Comment: @sql_dummy SQL standard does not define the order of evaluation of condition `x OR y AND z`, as opposed to for example Java, C++. The database is free to choose any order of evaluation it thiks is better. SQL is declarative language - I don't care about the order of evaluation, I only declare: "give me rows for which the condition `x OR y AND z` is true"

Comment: but will that not change the reult? Suppose if `x is true, y is false, z is false` in `case1` where condition will return false and in `case2` where condition will return true

Comment: I guess in oracle`AND` has more precedence than `OR`